# How to redirect to login page after page refresh

Tags: java, html, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile for my application and java at the server side. The user has to be redirected to the login page, i.e. index.html, if the user presses refresh button.

Can this be done using JavaScript or do I need to add java code to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

With JavaScript you can only handle the [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event. But you don't know if the user refreshes or navigates away. You need localstorage or cookies to keep your state and check if the user refreshes so you can redirect them. I don't even know if this is possible in the onbeforeunload event, but I would recommend you fix it server side. You need to have some logic server side.For example keep the last page in session and if it equals the new page redirect to your index.html.

Comment: Can you give an example code how can it be done on server-side?

Comment: I would use Session. Don't know exactly how it's done in jsp, but everytime a user navigates save it's url. Something like Session["url"] = navigatedUrl. Before the navigateurl is saved to the session check if it is the same 
if(Session["url"] == navigatedUrl){
   And redirect the user here 
}